# Access Recordsets and SQL Server with Pass Through Queries - If I update a field in the recordset, does it update the server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, recordset

I currently have a backend database using Microsoft SQL Server, and I am building a frontend interface with Microsoft Access.  Access interacts with the backend by way of pass-through queries, so all of the SQL statements are collected by forms, constructed in VBA, and then sent to the server directly.  This is because of network latency issues, and my understanding is that Access is inefficient when using linked tables and if it has to translate Access queries into T-SQL queries.

I now need to make a form that `SELECT`s from the database, updates one or multipe records/fields, and then `UPDATE`s the database.  Is it most efficient to:

- Update each record individually with its own query (the user would have to click a "Save" button or something
- Load the table into a Recordset object, make the changes locally, and then send one query to the server to batch update.  I could either make the changes in VBA or attach the Recordset to the form and let Access handle the updating of the Recordset

In the latter case, if an update is made to a Recordset object, will Access automatically write to the SQL server if the recordset is populated with a QueryDef in VBA code?

Comment: I think I have answered my own question.  Recordsets that are populated with a passthrough QueryDef are read only, so you basically have to edit each record individually?  Or is there some trick that you can do by loading things into a local table then somehow merging with the remote table?

Comment: I don't know what version of access you are using, but check out if an access project would work. You can open (and manipulate) tables using ADO in 2007

Comment: You can use ADO in basically any version of Access and you don't need to use an Access Data Project (.adp file) to use ADO. You can bind forms to updateable ADO recordsets and those recordsets can be the result of calling SQL Server Stored Procedures. ODBC Linked tables are easier to use than ADO but ADO is probably the more "enterprisy" way of accessing server side data from within MS Access.